# Selenium ChromeDriver On Dockers (Linux) failed to close

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, docker, debian, selenium-chromedriver

When I do

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(binary_location,chrome_options=options)
driver.get(URL)
...
driver.close()
```

its raise the following error:

```
'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Im using python 2.7 image on docker

After change binary to be executable

```
chmod a+x PATH_TO_DIR/chromedriver
```

It raise me the following error

```
ERROR: Message: unknown error: failed to close window in 20 seconds
(Session info: content shell=)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139 
(47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881),platform=Linux 4.11.0-1013-azure x86_64)
```

Comment: Did you check [this ticket](https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy/issues/391)?

Comment: @Andersson yeah, change the binary to be executable and fix that

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all :

```
'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

The error implies that in the following line of code :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(binary_location,chrome_options=options)
```

The program is expecting *chromedriver* executable within the arguments you have passed. But is unable to find the *chromedriver* executable.

So the solution would be instead of passing `binary_location` as an argument, you need to pass the absolute location of the *chromedriver* binary as follows :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
driver.get(URL)
```

*ChromeDriver* will find out the default `binary_location` from your *System Classpath* and initialize the *Chrome Browser*

---

### Update

If you still want to pass the `binary_location` explicitly well you can pass the absolute location of the *chrome* binary through `Options` class as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.binary_location('/path/to/chrome')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
driver.get('http://google.com/')
```

Comment: The binary its passed as argument, also before i checked if its found, the problem its no there :/

Comment: Yeah i pas the absolute path, the problem was i wasn´t changing the binary to be executable (update question)